# how to store date time in text file without offset +05:30

Tags: c#

I have stored `DateTimeOffset` into a text file like below,

```
DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString()
```

I noticed that it's stored as `"8/13/2020 2:11:31 PM +05:30"`, not sure why it's adding +05:30 and how can I remove it to +00:00.

I have other `DateTimeOffset` saved into database and it's returns as +00:00 and in below snap `x` is actually smaller than `z`, but it's going wrong here. The reason I am saving to text file add offset as +05:30.

How to fix this issue, database side I don't have any control and while saving into text file, how to can I eliminate to store time without offset?

- value for `x' coming from database
- value for `z` coming from text file read

[image]

Comment: Use `UtcNow` instead of `Now` and you'll get the time in UTC, where the offset is always `00:00`.

Comment: UtcNow, I can't use

Comment: Are you trying to establish one date before another? If so use ticks instead

Comment: If you want to store the _local_ time without the offset, then why are you using `DateTimeOffset` in the first place? Use `DateTime` instead: `DateTime.Now.ToString()`. Or if you have to use  `DateTimeOffset`, you could do: `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt")`. If on the other hand, you want to display the UTC time, then use `UtcNow`; why can't you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `storedTime.DateTime` then it is +00:00

Comment: it's ignore time, which is important for me

Comment: Ah okay then I missunderstood. In this case you should be able to call storedTime.DateTime. Then the Offsett should be gone (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257964/remove-time-zone-offset-from-datetimeoffset)