# C# Convert from and back to Unix timestamp

Tags: c#, timezone

I have following unit test which fails

```
[Fact]
public void Convert_to_and_from_unix_timestamp()
{
    // Arrange
    var timestamp = 1636579063;
    var date = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(timestamp).DateTime;

    // Act
    var unixTimeSeconds = ((DateTimeOffset)date).ToUnixTimeSeconds();

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(expected: timestamp, actual: unixTimeSeconds);

    // result
    // Expected: 1636579063 // 10/11/2021 21:17:43
    // Actual: 1636575463 // 10/11/2021 20:17:43
}
```

The new (actual) Unix timestamp is minus one hour. My machine timezone is UTC+1. Does it mean, that DateTimeOffset is automatically setting up my timezone (UTC+1) into the datetime and when converting back into the timestamp the DateTimeOffset is removing the UTC+1 so there is one hour decrease? How can I manage timezone in both ways?

Comment: yes. casting between DateTime and DateTimeOffset applies the local timezone. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37258500/1132334

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Time Zone Offset from DateTimeOffset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257964/remove-time-zone-offset-from-datetimeoffset)

Comment: `var date = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(timestamp).UtcDateTime;`, note `UtcDateTime` instead of `DateTime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `.DateTime` fragment in the line

```
    var date = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(timestamp).DateTime;
```

According to [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetimeoffset.cs,4cd26874e8103b68)

```
private DateTime ClockDateTime {
  get {
    // Here we lose Timezone (Offset) - it just added to m_dateTime
    // Kind is Unspecified, that's why we can restore the fact
    // Offset == 0 and we actually have UTC datetime    
    return new DateTime((m_dateTime + Offset).Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
  }
}
 
public DateTime DateTime {
  get {
    return ClockDateTime;
  }
}
```

.Net creates for `.DateTime` property a new `DateTime` instance with `Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, so you lose timezone (now `Offset` from `DateTimeOffset` is just *added* to `DateTime`).

In order to correct the test put `.UtcDateTime` instead of `.DateTime`:

```
    var date = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(timestamp).UtcDateTime;
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, it works and well explained! I did not know about MS reference source, very cool :-)